# Are the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $A_6$ Carter subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

By $A_6$ I mean the alternating group on $6$ letters, which is not solvable and so needn’t have Carter subgroups, but if they exist will still be conjugate. Since the sylow $2$-subgroups are conjugate, nilpotent and to me seem to be selfnormalizing, I’m wondering if this is true, and if hence the sylow $p$-subgroups for $p=3$ and $5$ cannot be selfnormalizing? As stated here and on Wikipedia, $A_5$ has no Carter subgroups. What is the situation for An when $n>6$? For one thing, since the Sylow $2$-subgroups in $A_6$ are selfnormalizing, wouldn’t they necessarily remain that way for larger $n$ by conjugating a part of the sylow $2$-subgroup that is in a part of the $A_n$ that has just $6$ letters?(And they would remain conjugate and nilpotent).

Comment: Yes the Sylow  $2$-subgroups of $A_n$ are self-normalizing for all $n \ge 6$ (although the argument that you give for this is not very convincing).

Comment: what am i missing?

Comment: You haven't proved anything.

Comment: i definitely did not phrase it as if it were a formal proof, so i assume that’s not exactly what you mean. What I presume you mean is that my argument doesn’t hold water, which is different from it being informal.

Comment: (I want to learn more about group theory. Why doesn’t it hold water, or is it not clear enough?

Comment: I cannot even begin to understand you argument. Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_2(A_n)$ for some $n>6$, and let's suppose we choose $P$ and a subgroup $H=A_6 < A_n$ such that $P \cap H \in {\rm Syl}_2(H)$; yes we can do that. So now we know that $N_H(P \cap H) = P \cap H$. But why do you think that implies that $P$ is self normalizing in $A_n$?

Comment: Let Q be the intersection of P and H, and let g be an element of H-Q. If g conjugates Q, it is still in H, but it is no longer Q. So Q^g is not a subgroup of P. So g isn't in the normalizer of P. But every g in An-P is in some copy of A6.

Comment: Your final statement is not true. For example, how could an element of order $7$ be in a copy of $A_6$?

Comment: Why am I so dumb? Well would the proof be repaired if I found out a way to show that every element in An-P is a product of elements in various copies of A6?

Comment: I know every even permutation is a product of 3 cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sylow-2 subgroups of $A_6$ are self-normalizing because there are 45 of them, and the order of $A_6$ is 8*45.

There are 45 because each is an index two subgroup of the $2\times D_8$ Sylows in $S_6$.  There are 15 ways to partition 6 points into 4 and 2 points, and, given that, 3 ways the $D_8$ can act on the four points, and these differences are preserved in $A_6$...e.g., one can have $(12)(3456)$, $(12)(3546)$, or $(12)(3465)$, in the Sylow, but these are all in distinct Sylows.

Thus a Sylow-2 in $A_6$ is a Carter subgroup.